# Explain behaviour of Numbers in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function

Number function in javascript can be used to multiply, divide, find remainder but cannot be used for subtraction and addition?

```
//I used theNumber = 3
var theNumber = Number ( prompt (" Pick a number " , "") ) ;
alert ("  difference  " + theNumber - theNumber ) ;
// Difference is NaN, why not 0?

var theNumber = Number ( prompt (" Pick a number " , "") ) ;
alert ("  sum  " + theNumber + theNumber ) ;
// ->33
```

why is concatenation occurring? why not 6?
please help!

Comment: try wrapping in parenthesis `alert("  sum  " + (theNumber + theNumber));`

Comment: `+` in javascript is used for concatenating strings. Like @jcubic said: use paranthesis and it calculates the sum.

Comment: You can use `console.log('difference', theNumber - theNumber)` in stead of `alert`s to log your results. That doesn't require your objects to be mapped to strings and may prevent these confusions.

Comment: Though it's not the direct cause here, you should note that everything that comes from `prompt()` is a **string**.

Answer (score 2):

Concatenation is occurring because it starts with a string:

```
alert ( "  sum  " + theNumber + theNumber ) ;
-> "string" + Number + Number = "StringNumberNumber"
```

The `+` after the string is treated as concatenation and not numerical addition operator from this point onwards. If you want to avoid this, you can wrap your addition in parenthesis:

```
alert ( "  sum  " + (theNumber + theNumber) ) ;
-> "String" + (Number + Number) = "StringEvaluatedParenthesis"
```

Answer (score 2):

## Coercion

In javascript if variables are operated on with conflicting types, then, the interpreter implicitly changes (coerces) variable types and operations.

## Operator Precedence and Associativity

Operations happen in accordance to [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

According to this source, (...) has a left to right associativity, which means it performs operations left to right.

So (5 + 4 + 6); will be broken down as:

1. 5 + 4 // returns 9
2. 9 + 6 // returns 15;

## Answer

Your question needs you to have knowledge on the above two topics.
Now,

```
var theNumber = Number ( prompt (" Pick a number " , "") ) ;
alert ("  difference  " + theNumber - theNumber ) ;
```

Difference NaN why not 0?

So apply you're new JS powers and think how the (...) work.

Assuming theNumber = 3;

1. " difference " + theNumber = " difference 3" (coercing theNumber to string)
2. " difference 3" - theNumber = NaN;

string + string is valid in JS in the form of concatenation, but '-' operator doesn't apply to strings, hence coercion happens again converting " difference 3" to a number which returns NaN.

```
console.log(NaN - 5);
```

**FUN FACT** : console.log(NaN - NaN); // is also NaN!

---

```
var theNumber = Number ( prompt (" Pick a number " , "") ) ;
alert ("  sum  " + theNumber + theNumber ) ;// ->3// ->33
```

This time:

1. "  sum  " + theNumber = "  sum  3"
2. "  sum  3" + theNumber = "  sum  33"

Comment: What you call precedence is in fact associativity.

Answer (score 0):

Because Javascript is not strictly typed language and needs to perform casting when it starts with a string, so the number 3 it is casted to a string and the output is their concatenation. If you add parenthesis (theNumber - theNumber) it will handle those two as numbers but then it will cast the result to a string to produce the output.

Some examples:

```
var stringValue = "1000";
```

This will cast the string to a number

```
var numericValue = +stringValue;
```

and this will make it string again

```
var stringAgain = "" + numericValue ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the unary plus operator to convert them to numbers first.

```
+num1 + +num2;
```

Comment: He used `Number()`

Comment: they are already numbers, that's what the `Number()`-function does

Answer (score 0):

This is mainly due to operator precedence

`-` and `+` has equal precedence they execute right to left order , so in case if you keep either `* or /` it works fine because They have high precedence

In `java script` the arithmetic operators are performed based on the `operands` this is why the concatenation is performed.

so if you enclose the operations of Arithmetic  iside the brackets `()` They get high precendense and execute first and then nex ...

So,Try like this

```
alert("diference " + (theNumber-theNumber))
```

Click [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence$revision/510297#Table) for more info

Comment: _"`-` has less precedence than `+`"_, no they have the _same_ precedence.  If `-` was lower, then `3 - 2 + 5` would be `-4`, but it's not, it's `6`.